# What's the easiest way to get the bearing (angle) of a segment of a linestring?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

In PostGIS/PostgreSQL, is there a function that gives the angle of the line segment of a linestring that a given point is on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On PostGIS version 1.5.3 [ST_Azimuth()](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Azimuth.html) required two points as input--true for all versions as far as I can tell--which I simply extracted from the line using  [ST_Line_Interpolate_Point()](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_Line_Interpolate_Point.html), like this:

```
ST_Azimuth(
  ST_Line_Interpolate_Point(wkb_geometry, 0.2), /* point at 20% length */
  ST_Line_Interpolate_Point(wkb_geometry, 0.8)  /* point at 80% length */
)/(2*pi())*360 as angle                         /* radians to degrees  */
```

Answer (score -1):

ST_Azimuth(geometry)

In a hurry :-)

/Nicklas

Comment: Perhaps this worked on an earlier version? As of 2.2 (at least) this will return an error because `ST_Azimuth` expects two arguments. Example failure: `SELECT ST_Azimuth('LINESTRING(0 0, 1 1, 2 2)'::geometry)`

Comment: ST_Azimuth expects point geometries. You can use the following code `SELECT ST_Azimuth(ST_StartPoint('LINESTRING(0 0, 1 1, 2 2)'::geometry), ST_EndPoint('LINESTRING(0 0, 1 1, 2 2)'::geometry))` in your LINESTRING example.